# Solving a PDE by substitution

Tags: partial-differential-equations

**Problem:**
Find the general solution to the PDE:

$$ 3u_y+u_{xy}=0, \quad (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \tag{1} $$

*Hint: consider the new function $v:=u_y$*

**Solution:**
The equation solved by $v$ is

$$ 3v(x,y)+v_x(x,y)=0 \tag{2} $$

which is an ODE in the variable x. **We solve the previous ODE for each fixed $y$.** Since the ODE is of the form $3f+f'=0$ it has the soluton $c_1 e^{-3x}$. However, the constant now can depend on $y$ (recall that we were solving *for each $y$*). Thus the general solution to the previous ODE is given by

$$ v(x,y)=g(y)e^{-3x} \tag{3} $$

for some function $y, g(y)$. If we compute $3v(x,y) + v_x(x,y)$ for this expression we get

$$ 3g(y)e^{-3x} + (-3)g(y)e^{-3x}=0 \tag{4} $$

so that any function $g$ can be taken as part of the solution. Now, recalling the definition of $v$, we have

$$ u_y(x,y)=g(y)e^{-3x} \tag{5} $$

which is, again, an ODE, but now in the $y$ variable. In particular, we integrate in $y$ to obtain

$$ u(x,y)=e^{-3x}\int_0^y g(\chi)d\chi + h(x) \tag{6} $$

where now $h(x)$ account for the integration constant for each $x$. Let us define $G(y):=\int_0^y g(\chi)d\chi$ so that $G(y)$ is differentiable, with derivative $g$. The general solution to our PDE is then

$$ u(x,y)=e^{-3x}G(y) + h(x) \tag{7} $$

for any functions $G$ and $h$, where $G$ is differentiable.

**Question:**
So I do get the solution in general. The only mistake I had when doing it myself was that my constants didn't depend on any variable, which makes intuitively sense. What I don't really get is the bold sentence below (2). How exactly do we fix $y$? And what would happen if we wouldn't?